# . Time Sheet includes travel time

Tags: human-resources

If an employee travel 200 miles (one way, about 3hrs) to attend 8 hours conference and come back the same day, can he/she charge travel time into his/her time sheet?

Comment: Are you paid hourly or salaried?  What does your boss say?

Comment: What location is this? Are they paying for travel? What does your contract say? or employee manual? Have you considered getting someone else to drive for you and charge your company for it?

Comment: Have you tried charging a per mile rate?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this will be entirely up to company policy and locale labor laws.  In the USA, many companies will only pay non-exempt workers (not management or professionals) for car travel time if the time is during the employee's normal work day.  Some companies will differentiate the driver from passengers.